# Rancher: High CPU utilization even with zero clusters under management

Tags: kubernetes, rancher

I am seeing a continuous 8 to 15% CPU usage on Rancher related processes while there is not a single cluster being managed by it. Nor is any user interacting with. What explains this high CPU usage when idle? Also, there are several "rancher-agent" containers perpetually running and restarting. Which does not look right. There is no Kubernetes cluster running on this machine. This machine (unless Rancher is creating its own single node cluster for whatever reason).

I am using Rancher 2.3

docker stats:
[image: docker stats output]

docker ps:
[image]

htop:
[image: htop output]

[image: Rancher version info]

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I would call 15% "high", but Kubernetes has a lot of ongoing stuff even if it looks like the cluster is entirely quiet. Stuff like processing node heartbeats, etcd election traffic, controllers with time-based conditions which have to be processed. K3s probably streamlines that a bit, but 0% CPU usage is not a design goal even in the fork.

Comment: No Kubernetes Cluster is running! It is just rancher.

Comment: Rancher itself runs on top of a local k3s cluster, as you can see in your images.

Answer (score 2):

- Rancher (2.3.x) does not do anything involving k3s.  These pictures are not "just Rancher".
- k3s is separately installed and running.
- The agents further suggest that this node is added to a cluster (maybe the same Rancher running on it, maybe not).
- It restarting all the time is not helping CPU usage, especially if it is registered to that local Rancher instance.
- Also you're running a completely random commit from head instead of an actual release.

Comment: I had configured it once as a Kubernetes node. But since rancher is all docker based, I thought stopping and pruning the containers should have cleaned off any Kubernetes stuff. Could you tell how to get rid of it?

Answer (score 0):

FWIW...In my case, I built the raspberry pi based Rancher/k3 lab as designed by Network Chuck on youtube.  The VM on my linux host that runs Rancher will start off fairly quiet, then over the course of a couple of days the rancherd process will consistently hit near 100% cpu usage (I gave it 3 vcpu's) and stay there, even though I have no pods running on either the pi cluster or the local Rancher VM cluster.  A reboot starts the process over, but within a few days its back to 100% cpu usage.
On writing this I just noticed that due to a DHCP issue, my original external ip for the local rancher cluster node got changed from 163 to 151 (I reserved it in pihole to 151, just never updated rancher config).  Just fixed it in the Rancher gui, we'll see if that clears up some of the errors I saw in the logs and keeps the CPU usage normal on idle.